# DDL source Z1127_EXTVIEW of type ABAP Dictionary Type cannot be converted to Extend (-> long text)

Tags: abap, cds

**I have the table `Z1127_STUDENT`:**

```
define table z1127_student {
  key id     : z1127_sample not null;
  branch     : z1127_sample1;
  age        : z1127_age;
  address    : z1127_address;
  percentage : z1127_percent;
}
```

(the types of the columns are based on the types `int2` and `char`)

**and the CDS view `Z1127_CDS_VIEWS`:**

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'Z1127_CDSVIEWS'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
@EndUserText.label: 'CDS VIEWS'
define view Z1127_CDS_VIEWS as select from z1127_student
{
key id,
branch,
age
}
```

**I tried to create this extended view :**

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewAppendName: 'Z1127_SQL_3'
@EndUserText.label: 'cds view 3'

extend view Z1127_CDS_VIEWS with z1127_cds3 {

    address, 
    percentage
}
```

But it's showing this error :

> DDL source z1127_cds3 of type ABAP Dictionary Type cannot be converted to Extend (-> long text)

How to avoid this error?

Comment: did you try to comment your view extension? table and Z1127_CDS_VIEWS view activates successfully?

Comment: i comment extension view. Z1127_CDS_VIEWS activates successfully the error is shown in extension view only

Comment: I recreated you config with the [following table](https://imgur.com/Htq5JR4) and with absolutely identical view and extension and my extension activated successfully. I believe the problem lies in your table Z data elements. I deliberately didn't specify table enhancement category to recreate exactly your case, so enh.cat. is not the point here

Comment: what ABAP release do you have?